# How to determine the OSX process which is presenting a dialog?

Tags: macos, troubleshooting

Today when restarting a MacBook Air I got a pop-up stating "The managed object model version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent store."

[image: OSX Error Dialog]

However there is nothing indicating which app or process triggered this. Clicking on the dialog doesn't switch application. Is there a way to find out what is producing this message (while it is still open)? I tried searching for the log message in `/Library/Logs` `~/Library/Logs` and `/var/log` but found nothing.

Comment: `xwininfo` (run it in a terminal) may help you. I think you'll have to run it, then click on the dialog. I'm unsure if it still exists in OSX...

Comment: The `xwininfo` command exists but clicking in the dialog (or any other window) did not have any result.

Comment: Thanks @djsmiley2k ! Adding `xwininfo` to my search terms helped me track down a solution.

Comment: This happened right after I updated to 10.13.4 today

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to track this down using `Accessibility Inspector.app` (which I think is bundled with XCode). See the answer to
[How to identify a process from a toolbar icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232427/283968).